# Inclusion of a js file in HTML

Tags: javascript, header

I am include a huge javascript file(500K) in my HTML. Is there a smart way to know if it has been loaded. One way I can think of is to have a variable in its constructor to initialize and inform me . The loading is asynchronous and I cannot proceed until function s of that JS are included.

Thanks

Comment: If you can't proceed without loading the file, why load it asynchronously?

Comment: The HTML currently has asynch loading, probably because the js file is so big. So why do you want to remove that functionality?

Comment: Ever used Microsoft Sharepoint? They have JS files of that size! Caused some consternation with our reps with slow telephone connections...

Comment: Its OpenLayers.js compressed to 500k
How to load synchronously ?

Comment: Load synchronously as done in Oscar's answer. Any Javascript you put below it will only be executed after this file has loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using jQuery you can handle a callback function that runs when the script file is loaded:

```
$.getScript("yourScriptFile.js", function(){
  // What to do when the script is loaded
});
```

[Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript)

Comment: Unless You already use jQuery this means another 15/30kB data to your already huge script requirement.

Answer (score 3):

As an clarification on Oscar's answer:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 alert('the file has loaded!'); 
 //Anything here will not be executed before the script.js was loaded
</script>
```

Also if the file is huge, it might be better to load it after the page has loaded, so that you, on slow connections can use the page before it's loaded:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
 Nothing here will be rendered until the script has finished loading
</body>
```

Better is to:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
 I will be rendered immidiatly
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</html>
```

That way users get the page fast and only then have to wait for the javascript functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="filename">
</SCRIPT>
```

??

Comment: yep. This is the usual method. I need to know, if inclusion is done

Comment: If you use this method it's best to put it not in the header, but after the body tag of your page, that way the page will render first and only then start loading the 500kb of javascript, thus having your page visible fast on slow connections.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compressing the javascript file? Moving some of the functions into separate Javascript files, and only including the needed javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function at the end of the script file which would inform the script on the page that it's ready for use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the question may be restated: how do I know my script is loaded in a html-page? Placing the script at the bottom of the page you make sure all the DOM-elements are available to your script. When you want to know if your script is available, you should check if the function to run is available. Maybe this constructor can help:

```
function Wait(what,action,id){
 var _x = this,
     rep = document.getElementById('report'),
     cnt = 0,
     timeout = 5,
     interval = 100;

  _x.id = id;

  if (!(what instanceof Function)) {
   return true; //or say something about it
  }

  function dowait() {
   cnt += interval;
   if (what())
   {
      clearInterval(_x.iv);
      action();
      return true;
   }
   if (cnt>(timeout*1000))
   {
      clearInterval(_x.iv);
          //[do some timeout-action]
      return true; 
   }
 }
 _x.iv = setInterval(dowait,interval);
```

}

The constructor takes a function (returning a boolean) as its first argument. Like

```
function(){return document.getElementById('someelement').innerHTML = '';}
```

So if you include this before your javascript, you can do something like:

```
var testfn = 
     function(){return document.getElementById('someElement').innerHTML = '';},
   callback = 
     function(){alert('someElement is empty')},
   dummy = null;
window.onload=function(dummy=new Wait(testfn,calllback);
```